# Obtain means within site and year in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with multiple sites that were each sampled over multiple years. As part of this I have climate data that were sampled throughout each year as well as calculated means for several variables (mean annual temp, mean annual precipitation, mean annual snow depth, etc). Here is what the data frame actually looks like:

```
site  date  year  temp  precip  mean.ann.temp  mn.ann.precip
a   5/1/10  2010   15       0       6                   .03
a   6/2/10  2010   18       1       6                   .03
a   7/3/10  2010   22       0       6                   .03
b   5/2/10  2010   16       2       7                   .04
b   6/3/10  2010   17       3       7                   .04
b   7/4/10  2010   20       0       7                   .04
c   5/3/10  2010   14       0       5                   .06
c   6/4/10  2010   13       0       5                   .06
c   7/8/10  2010   25       0       5                   .06
d   5/5/10  2010   16      15       10                  .2
d   6/6/10  2010   22       0       10                  .2
d   7/7/10  2010   24       0       10                  .2
...
```

It then goes on the same way for multiple years.

How can I extract the mean.ann.temp and mn.ann.precip for each site and year? I've tried doubling up tapply() with no success and using double for loops, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me? Or do I have to do it the long and tedious way of just subsetting everything out?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subset the columns and wrap it in a `unique`.

```
unique(d[,c("site","year","mean.ann.temp","mn.ann.precip")])
```

A similar way if the last two columns are different, and you want the first row:

```
d[!duplicated(d[,c("site","year")]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

To compute summaries using `plyr`

```
require(plyr)
ddply(yourDF, .(site,year), summarize, 
  meanTemp=mean(mean.ann.temp),
  meanPrec=mean(mn.ann.precip)
)
```